# Wordpress live video streaming plugin

Tags: wordpress, live-streaming

Anyone know wordpress plugin for live video streaming ?

I know this is not a forum to ask this kind of questions.But I searched it Google and found one plugin its very expensive its more than $1000 per year.

I want plugin for reasonable price.

Any help please 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below the links will help you to find out the best WordPress plugin for you

https://www.kasareviews.com/best-wordpress-webinar-plugin/

http://www.wpexplorer.com/best-webinar-plugins-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks I got the details from the link

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpstream/ ( https://wpstream.net ) - they have a free plan for testing